# SystemJs error after updating to Angular2 RC6

Tags: angular, systemjs

I updated to RC6 (from RC5) and after using the example systemjs.config.js from [angular quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/3b7452cc444c49c139ea39523ced0468c2362c16/systemjs.config.js#L17-L34) I'm receiving the error **(SystemJS) SyntaxError: Unexpected token**.  I used the quickstart example config and added a few more map items for packages that my app uses (listed below).  Other than that it's the same config as in the example.

> ```
>         'ng2-bootstrap': 'npm:ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js',
>         'moment': 'npm:moment/moment.js',
>         'primeng': 'npm:primeng/primeng.js',
>         'angular2-jwt': 'node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js',
>         'lodash': 'npm:lodash/lodash.js'
> ```

Comment: Unexpected token is usually a syntax error - a missing or extra quote, a missing comma, or something like that.  For me it usually is a missing comma or an added semi-colon because I always forget to add one (the comma) or not add the other (the semi-colon) when writing object definitions.

Comment: @Steven-Luke, I downloaded [angular quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/tree/3b7452cc444c49c139ea39523ced0468c2362c16) and added the additional packages (listed above) that I use in my app and added them to the systemjs.config.js (as specified above) and then started the app and it ran with no problem.  In my app I had made no changes to my code, I only updated to RC6 and updated the systemjs config.  I also tried deleting everything from node-modules and reinstalled all packages, still no luck.

Comment: I've taken the quickstart and moved my app code into that project and it's making progress (even though the app running from my VS2015 project still has the same error).  In the quickstart verison of the app, I now get errors like this: GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js/ng2-bootstrap 404 (Not Found)
Not sure why it's putting the extra /ng2-bootstrap on the url, otherwise the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering around I made the following modifications to fix the problem.

The map entries in the original question were changed to this

```
    'moment': 'npm:moment/moment.js',
    'angular2-jwt': 'npm:angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js',
    'ng2-bootstrap': 'npm:ng2-bootstrap',
    'primeng': 'npm:primeng',
    'lodash': 'npm:lodash'
```

Then I added these package definitions

```
    primeng: { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ng2-bootstrap': {
        main: 'ng2-bootstrap.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    lodash: {
        main: 'index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
```

The error message threw me off (as well as a lack of understanding what the settings in the systemJS config are actually doing).